# Azur "Error message: \"Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: invalid uri fileUri_{1}\r\ninvalid uri fileUri_{2}\r\ninvalid u

Tags: azure

Azure Custom script execution failed, please help for fix.

"Error message: "Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: invalid uri fileUri_{1}\r\ninvalid uri fileUri_{2}\r\ninvalid uri fileUri_{3}\r\n"\r\n\r\nMore information on troublesho"

[image]

Custom Script for windows :-  Installing IIS service

import-module servermanager
add-windowsfeature web-server  -includeallsubfeature
add-windowsfeature Web-asp-Net45
add-windowsfeature NET-framework-Features

Error :-
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"VMExtensionProvisioningError","message":"**VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CustomScriptExtension'. Error message: "Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: invalid uri fileUri_{1}\r\ninvalid uri fileUri_{2}\r\ninvalid uri** fileUri_{3}\r\n"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "}]}

Comment: Well, what is the error message from `operation details` ? Share your custom extension script

Comment: thanks for asking , adding above for customer windows script

Comment: What does the ARM template look like for the script execution?

Comment: Don't include photos, include the actual code

Comment: i am not using the template ,  i am provisioning the VM of Windows with customer script execution ,.

Answer (score 2):

After further checking able to fix the issue as below.

1. Custom script name should be as per azure suggested, earlier I had given (under score, Capital Letter while naming the Storage Account, that is the main error.
2. Deployment  Error :-
   [image]
3. Before changing the Name Error naming :-
   [image]
4. After the overwriting the Name as below format:-
   [image]
5. Installed the Custom Extension Script , got installed as below.

[image]